# Why does each key have different fingering on the erhu?

Tags: fingering, erhu

Why does each key ...playing the erhu have different fingering ? Is there a way to understand why and if I understand the logic, I might be able to figure out what fingering I should be using. I have no problem playing the usual notation.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "different fingering". Were you previously playing an instrument where you could go through all 12 keys without altering your fingering? I mean, even on the sax the fingerings are different for each key for me, so I'm not exactly sure what you find surprising or difficult to understand.

Comment: Please provide some background: are you taking lessons?  Do you have experience with other instruments?  and so on

Comment: I agree with the comments that you'd need to provide some additional background information. What other instruments do you play?

Answer (score 1):

First of all the ehru is not a western instrument so I'd as are you playing western scales on it, Major etc?  Or eastern scales which may be different.

The thing that is constant in western music is the steps in the scale.  For the major scale starting on any note you progress by steps as follows: whole, whole, half, whole, whole, whole, half.  Where the steps are taken from the last note played and a whole = 2 halves.

I'd point out that even on the guitar the open string scales each have different fingering, the fingering only becomes "standard" in a sense when you move up the neck.  I am not sure this applies to your instrument.  But I hope it helps.